# Why is Homebrew not creating python binding files on OS X 10.8?

Tags: python, opencv, homebrew

I'm trying to use OpenCV with PySide on a Mac with Mountain Lion. The Homebrew formula works fine, but the python binding files do not show up.

```
romaindeterre$ brew install opencv
==> Downloading http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-unix/2.4.3/Op
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/opencv-2.4.3.tar.bz2
==> cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.3 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=None 
==> make
==> make install
==> Caveats
The OpenCV Python module will not work until you edit your PYTHONPATH like so:
   export PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH"

To make this permanent, put it in your shell's profile (e.g. ~/.profile).
==> Summary
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.3: 214 files, 51M, built in 108 seconds
```

The `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` does not contain any file named `cv.*`.

I did `brew update` and the output of `brew doctor` is below :

> Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew
>   directories. `./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to
>   determine if software packages are installed, and what additional
>   flags to use when compiling and linking.
>
> Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed
>   via Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew
>   provided script of the same name. We found the following "config"
>   scripts:
>
> ```
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python-config
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2-config
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-config
> ```

Is there anything I am missing to install OpenCV properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would really recommend using pip and a virtualenv for python development. On the Mac this hitchhikers guide is a great read on how to set it up. Using a virtualenv will create an isolated python path and using pip to install things within the virtual env will really help here.

https://python-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/starting/install/osx/

Comment: This is the first time I've seen this guide but it looks very helpful. reading it now, thanks! I would upvote you but I'm not qualified to tell how well it answered this particular question. Thanks for the reference.